# In LAN , One System cant access some Websites except Google

Tags: browser, operating-systems, virus

In Our Office we are facing some weird problem , one of our staff PC unable to open may websites except Google and other websites .

PC is   re formatted and stored fresh Windows Xp but still getting the problem but in others staffs PC , they can easily access all the websites .

We have formatted 2 times by deleting all the partition and reformatted and installed OS. but still we are not able to open many websites including Microsoft website for windows updating.

can any body guess what happening here in the affected PC

Comment: is your workplace using a proxy server?

Comment: @Robotnik, No , this is happening with only one PC

Comment: ah, sorry missed the part where you said other staff's PCs could access other websites. Sorry that's the only thing I could think of

Comment: Can you access other sites via Google?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Check if your computer and the other where the other sites works are in the same network. You can see it by executing command: ifconfig /all

Comment: A comment, not an answer, because I'm speculating ... but I have seen one machine infected with a rootkit virus resident in a *hidden* partition on the drive. I thought the drive was clean until I happened to use a different partition tool (a linux based one on a live boot DVD) and saw a 12MB boot partition at the *end* of the drive. Deleted that, reformat and repartition the drive, yet another install of XP and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure that, will it work for you or not, But, you should give it a try to change default MTU setting. This Microsoft article will help you to change MTU Settings: - 
[Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826159)

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try

Can you ping websites (not Google) like ping www.yahoo.com ?

Go to control panel, Open network connections, right click on the local and select properties. Click Internet Protocol in the list, and select properties.
 Is this dynamic?
From here, click on Advanced. Are the IP DHCP enabled?
Click DNS tab. Are there any entries?
Click WINS. I can't remember this but try to disable the NetBios and try a website. If this doens't work, enable it and try.
Click Options tab. Click properties. Ensure that this is not enabled (ie unchecked)

As unlikely as this is as it's a new format, check the hosts file C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc (open hosts with notepad) and make sure you don't have a long list of blocked sites etc

I dont' suppose you have any external devices plugged in (like USB etc)? Clutching at straws here, but these are the best places to hide malicious code as some AV's don't scan them.